# query performance issues interacting with two databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-performance

I am writing a program to get values from MySQL database and insert into file.

My Database is very large containing around 15 million records. So after some time the program becomes slow as the reason might me more number of table scanning happens.

My program structure is like that, I am taking some value from the database in the resultset and looping each value from the resultset and insert this value in the where clause of select query to fetch data from different database and finally get the value.

Here is the sample code:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    String query = "SELECT empID from Employee where name="+name;
    rs2 = stm.executeQuery(query);
}
```

I wanted to know the solution where the time for the select query in the loop gets constant or some other solution which improve the performance.

Comment: can you add more information about you db

Comment: Each iteration will just replace the previous resultSet, rs2. Is this intended? Can you not create one query joining the 2 tables?

Comment: Based on first query result are you fetching value from different database or table?

Comment: what is the first query for which you get the ResultSet? It must be possible to combine them into a single query with a JOIN

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: what would happen if name= x;drop table Employee; ?

Comment: I am fetching the values from different database

Comment: @RahulMittal, the fact that you are fetching the employee names from a different database is ***by far the most important part*** of your question. Please edit your question to explain your situation more clearly.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a string of names from the first resultset and using an IN statement with all the names? This would result in only 1 query to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the comments that your Java program has the responsibility of joining, on the client side, information from two different data bases. This is notoriously difficult, especially when both data bases are large.

In cases where there are a lot of changes to the data are going on, you're going to have a hard time producing consistent results. This may be OK, but you have to program defensively around the data changing underneath your process.

I would, if I were you, start my program by retrieving all the name / id pairs from the `stm` database connection. I would put them in a HashMap. Then while reading from the `rs` result set I would look up the ids from the names in the HashMap. This strategy will cost some memory but will eliminate the nested query.

Here is a sketch of the code. It is not debugged. I don't have time to debug it for you, sorry to say. If you're going to put this in your program you need to understand it well enough to debug it.

```
/* preload name and empID values into a hashmap */
HashMap<String, Integer> name_id = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String query = "SELECT name, empID from Employee";
rs2 = stm.executeQuery(query);
while (rs2.next()) {
    String name = rs2.getString("name");
    Integer id = rs2.getInteger("empID);
    name_id.put(name, id);
}
rs2.close();

/* loop over the result set from the other database */
while(rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    Integer empID = name_id.get(name);
}
```

Here the `name_id.get()` function takes the place of the query in your question. Because you have preloaded all the name/id pairs into memory, this will be ***very*** fast compared to a query for each row in your `rs` resultset.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid full scans of the `Employee` table, verify you have an appropriate covering index:

```
... ON `Employee` (`name`, `empID`)
```

An `EXPLAIN SELECT ..` will show the execution plan used by MySQL.

(NOTE: this only addresses the performance of the query shown. This doesn't address the performance issue of repeated executions.)